# Scala syntax is difficult to understand

Tags: scala, akka

I am learning Scala and Akka, I am basically Java programmer. I am seeing variety of syntax, but few I am not able to understand.

```
case class ProcessStringMsg(string: String)
case class StringProcessedMsg(words: Integer)

class StringCounterActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ProcessStringMsg(string) => {
      val wordsInLine = string.split(" ").length
      sender ! StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine)
    }
    case _ => println("Error: message not recognized")
  }
}
```

Here, what is the meaning of `sender ! StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine)`?

Comment: It's just a [method](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.actor.ActorRef@!(message:Any)(implicitsender:akka.actor.ActorRef):Unit) call. Methods can (and often are) be symbolic in Scala.

Comment: kindly explain  ! operator will do please.

Comment: It's not an operator, it's just a method call. It calls the method `!`. That's all it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `foo.bar(baz)` can be written as `foo bar baz` in Scala. Notice that we are omitting `.` here. `.` is optional in this case (case where method takes only one parameter)
>
> `sender ! StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine)` can be understood as `sender.!(StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine))`

But With respect to implementation

`sender ! StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine)` is akin to `sender.tell(StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine))`

*taken from akka codebase*

```
final def tell(msg: Any, sender: ActorRef): Unit = this.!(msg)(sender)

override def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit = 
  actorCell.sendMessage(message, sender)
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more doubt, how it know it have to call 'tell' method if you use '!', is 'tell' method is any default method or any operator overloading method to do the job of 'tell' method.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things about scala syntax that should help a java programmer:

- method names in scala do not have to be alpha-numeric. `!` is as valid name for a method, as "foo"
- a dot between an instance and a member being referenced is optional, and so are parenthesis, around a single method argument.  `foo.bar("baz")` is equivalent to `foo bar baz`

With that in mind, notice that `sender ! StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine)` is the same as `sender.!(StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine))`: it calls a method named `!` on `sender` and passes `StringProcessedMsg(wordsInLine)` to it as a parameter.

Nothing magical :)

Answer (score 2):

The `!` operator sends a message to an actor [Here is documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/actors.html#actors-tell-sender-scala)

Its not the only way to send messages to an actor in Scala there is also Ask however you need to understand the differences before using ask all over the place.